# tkinter/py2app created application doesn't show window on initial launch

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, py2app

I'm running into an issue where launching a python app created with Tkinter and packaged by py2app doesn't show the application window immediately. The only way I've gotten the window to show after launch is to click on the application icon in the dock.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003707/sdl-based-app-doesnt-show-window-upon-launch) is using an applescript to auto-click the app on launch but as he states, and I agree, it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After doing some extensive research, it would appear that this is a result of setting the 'argv_emulation' option to True in the, py2app, setup.py file.

Comment: Thanks, saved me some time. FYI, argv_emulation: "# this puts the names of dropped files [onto the OS X app] into sys.argv when starting the app." See http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X for more info

Comment: Yup, setting `argv_emulation` to `False` worked for me.