# py2app’s window (wxPython) doesn’t come to front on launch

Tags: python, cocoa, wxpython, py2app

After compiling an `.app` using `py2app`, the `wxPython`-based app doesn't come to the front on launch. It hides behind other apps, and only when I click on the dock icon does it show.

I tried a whole bunch of focus methods, both in `wxPython` as well as in `Cocoa`, to no avail.

When I execute the app in Sublime Text, however, the window comes to the front instantly.

What am I doing wrong?

It's `Mac 10.13.2`, `wxPython 4.0.0b2`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer searching for different search words.

From [tkinter/py2app created application doesn't show window on initial launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992316/tkinter-py2app-created-application-doesnt-show-window-on-initial-launch):
"After doing some extensive research, it would appear that this is a result of setting the 'argv_emulation' option to True in the, py2app, setup.py file."

Problem solved.